# how to extract an interferogram from an IR Spectrum in python using the inverse Fourier transform

Tags: python-3.x, fft

I'm trying to extract an interferogram from the spectrum using the inverse Fourier transform, I have a graph as a function of wavelength (in cm^(1)) and the corresponding interferogram should be as a function of retardation (distance) with also negative values

the IR spectrum looks like the following:
[IR Spectrum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QimTT.png)

the interferogram should look something like this:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDvzh.png)